# Connected components and continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This may be a stupid question. If $X$ is a topological space, I know that being a connected subset of $X$ is not necessarily equivalent to being a path connected subset of $X$. But does it hold that two elements $x,y \in X$ are in the same connected component if it possible to construct a continuous map $f: [0,1] \to X$ such that $f(0) = x$ and $f(1) = y$?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise you could construct a disconnection of the connected set $f([0,1])$. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669915/path-components-or-connected-components) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since path-connectedness implies connectedness, the path connected components are also connected and so if two points lie in the same path connected component they must have to lie in the same connected component.

Comment: Thanks! I am now convinced. :-)